# Is there any software (open source or otherwise) that can mimic Yubikey functionality using a device's built in biometric hardware?

Tags: windows, open-source, two-factor-authentication

Let's say I'm using a laptop that includes both a fingerprint scanner and a IR camera for facial recognition. Is there any software that can make use of this existing hardware that would essentially act like a Yubikey, but without the Yubikey?

It seems to me that when Yubikey was created, biometric scanners where not commonly integrated into our devices, so this was a gap that Yubikey saw and filled. But now as more devices commonly have these technologies built in, I'm wondering if anyone has created software that takes advantage of this.

To be clear, I understand that Yubikey is categorized as *something you have* while biometrics are categorized as *something you are*. In this case, I'm saying that the *something I have* is the laptop I'm using, and I want to use the built in hardware (biometric capabilities) to go the additional step to meet *something you are*.